# XSLT to transform HTML to Markdown not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, xslt, markdown

I'm using the XSLT found [here](http://symphony-cms.com/download/xslt-utilities/view/20573/) to transform content in HTML to Markdown format but the results I'm getting are plain text without the Markdown formatting syntax. Here's the function I'm using:

```
private static string ConvertToText()
{
    string text = string.Empty;

    XmlDocument xsl = new XmlDocument();
    xsl.CreateEntityReference("nbsp");
    xsl.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Test/markdown.xslt"));

    XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Test/html.xml"));

    //creating stringwriter
    StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();

    XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
    xslt.Load(xsl);
    xslt.Transform(xr, null, writer);

    //return string
    text = writer.ToString();
    writer.Close();

    return text;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why it's not working?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a small sample of input XML, provide the output which is produced, and contrast this with what you expected to come out?

Comment: We'll also need to see the XSLT

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is the xmlns in your input XML. Try either to remove it in the `xr` variable before you transform it or to adjust your XSL file with namespace declarations like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
...
<xsl:template match="html:h3">
...
```